# Can I substitute the value of enter/return?

Tags: key-bindings, list

I am looking to insert list items

```
to-buy
> apple
> milk
>
```

but I would like to insert a constant string (" > ") on each newline

is there a way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure if I completely follow your question; what is your input, and what is the expected output?

Comment: enter -> "\n > "

Answer (score 1):

Well maybe it is not exactly what you want, but why not use such subst command after insert finished:

```
'[+1,']s/^/> /
```

Where

- `'[+1` is second inserted line number
- `']` is last inserted line number
- `s` - subst command
- `^` - start of line (position after "enter")
- `>`  - replacement text

You can map this to key for example:

```
nnoremap <F4> :'[+1,']s/^/> /<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remap the behaviour of `<cr>` in insert-mode to a custom function that checks whether you are on a line starting with any amount of whitespace, then `>` then any other characters. If so, enter a new-line and start with `>`, otherwise enter a new-line as normal.

```
function! MakeNewLine()
    if getline(line('.')) =~# "^\s*>.*$"
        execute "normal! a\<cr>> "
        startinsert!
    else
        execute "normal! a\<cr>"
        normal! ^
        startinsert
    endif
endfunction
inoremap <cr> <esc>:call MakeNewLine()<cr>
```

Put this in your `~/.vimrc`, `~/_vimrc` or equivalent so it is run every time you run vim. When you enter a new-line in a `>` list in the middle of an entry, this also has the effect of splitting it into two entries.

Comment: I think we can simplify your code: see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/statox/d5ae227a8eb96b882f23cba124e40649). You don't need `execute` for your `normal!` commands, we can use `o` instead of `a\<cr>`, I don't think `normal! ^` is useful here and if you use `<c-o>` instead of `<esc>` in your mapping you don't need `startinsert` anymore. (Also you may want to put the function in an `autoload` directory but that's not the most important.)